# How would I hook into rake's tasks to time how long each takes, to try to eliminate slow bits of build script?

Tags: performance, optimization, continuous-integration, build-automation, rake

I'm interested in knowing which parts of my rake-based build (running within TeamCity) is slow.  Is there an MVC-filter-style way I can wrap rake-tasks so that each one runs within a timer, and I output a breakdown of

- time-spent on task including prerequisites (I guess the time between invoke starting and execute finishing)
- time-spent on task excluding prerequisites (I guess the time between execute starting and finishing)

so that I can analyse which parts of my build are taking the most time, to target my optimisation efforts?

Does TeamCity have any features baked in that would do this for me?  (I know I'll be able to chart the results of my performance-logging with custom-charts; I just wondered whether it could do this out of the box already.)

Answer (score 0):

First, in TeamCity 6.0 there is a tree view of the build log. In this tree view you can see duration times spent for different blocks of your build.

Also, in TeamCity's rake runner, there is "Track invoke/execute stages" option, which can be enabled to get more information in your build log (and there is timing information for each record).

You can also try adding rake parameters like -t or -v in TeamCity rake settings to get more verbose output.

TeamCity also allows you to use [custom service messages](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) to provide more information to your log and to your build.

Hope this helps,
KIR

Comment: I need to do it locally, too, so that timing information gets pushed into a log file (CSV, by preference).  I'm using this to profile build-performance on developer workstations to put a case together for upgrades.